# getContext() returns Null

Tags: android, file-io, android-contentprovider

I am using getContext() method in Android to get the Context and then create files. But, I consistently get a null pointer exception when the app is invoked from a crash, and then getContext() is accessed.

Below is my code which invokes after the crash. This code works fine before the crash but fails after the crash.

```
synchronized public void insertR(String filename,String content) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String filename = filename;
    String string = content;
    Context context = MyActivity.getAppContext();

    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    try {//Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        Log.v("insertR", content);
        System.out.println(filename);
        System.out.println(context); //prints null

        outputStream = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 } }

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public static Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_dynamo);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
}
public static Context getAppContext() {
    try {
        return context;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return MyActivity.getAppContext();
    }
}}
```

Comment: in which class is the method `insertR()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `insertR()` method like this:

```
synchronized public void insertR(Context context, String filename,String content) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String filename = filename;
    String string = content;

    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {//Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        Log.v("insertR", content);
        System.out.println(filename);
        System.out.println(context); //prints null

        outputStream = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

If you want to call it from MainActivity do it like this:

```
insertR(this, fileName, content);
```

or

```
insertR(getApplicationContext(), fileName, content);
```

Comment: insertR() is in a class which extends ContentProvider and I am calling insertR() from an AsyncTask thread.

Comment: Make the above changes and test it

Comment: As I am in another Async class I cannot use "getApplicationContext()"
So, used Context context = MyActivity.getAppContext();
and tried the second option. I am still getting the error.

Comment: Then in the constructor of that class you must pass this context, store it in a variable and pass it on to InsertR(). There is no other way

Answer (score 0):

I believe since you are in an activity you can use the static function `getApplicationContext()` to retrieve the context.

Comment: I am in Async class and so cannot use, getApplicationContext().

Comment: Create yourself a provider: https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2013/04/27/android-get-application-context/#.W2ILbkxFxBs